# XAML data chain-binding issue

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, binding, uwp-xaml

I am working on a UWP application and i have created a custom `Date Picker control` and a custom `Time Picker control` which are child to a parent custom `Date-Time Picker Control`. The parent control has a property called `SelectedDateTime` which is the combination of the selection from two child controls. This property is binded correctly to child's properties in a two-way fashion but updating child's property does not update the parent' property.

[Parent Control Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsxkk.png)

[Parent Control Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUZ5T.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. code for the parent's SelectedDateTime property and also the Binding could be useful

Comment: @Nikhileshwar i have updated my post, please let me know what you think

Comment: Are the `SelectedDate` and `SelectedTime` property of the same type as `SelectedDateTime`. If they are of same type too, how can a time and date property can have the same value. I would suggest you to use two more property separately in your DateTime picker for Date and Time and alter the SelectedDateTime on the property changed method accordingly or use a Converter.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, i am doing the same as you mentioned(i had a remove a bunch of code, due to company policies). Those individual controls works fine, the problem i have right now is with the binding, the XAML acknowledges the binding as valid but the two properties fail to talk to each other.

Comment: Hi @Milindm2 , If modifying the child does not change the property in the parent, there may be a problem with the binding. Since I don't see the complete code, I can't determine the real reason. You can try to create a `UserControl` (that is, without using `ControlTemplate`) for binding. In XAML-Code Behind, binding will be easier to implement and understand.